# Hyperledger Composer multi-user mode: ECONNREFUSED for issued identities

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I've been following [Caroline's blog](https://medium.com/@CazChurchUk/developing-multi-user-application-using-the-hyperledger-composer-rest-server-b3b88e857ccc) to setup a multi-user composer rest server. So, I have two servers viz. Admin Server and the User Server.

As mentioned in the tutorial I:

1. Started the Admin Server with no authentication and single user mode. I started this server with Admin's card.
2. Started the User Server with JWT authentication in multi-user mode. I started this server with Admin's card as well.
3. Created a User participant and generated a card for user from the admin server.
4. Exchanged the first JWT token for this user on the User Server. So now the user has an access token.
5. Using this access-token I imported the user's card generated in #3 into the User Server.
6. Checked the Wallet status using user's access-token and was able to see the card to be set as default. i.e. default:true

This seems to have worked fine. However, now I'm trying to ping the network using User Server and User's access token. And it results in:

> Error: Error trying login and get user Context. Error: Error trying to enroll user or load channel configuration. Error: Calling enrollment endpoint failed with error [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:7054]

I tried setting this card to be default again but with no luck. When I list the identities issued from the admin server, I'm able to see this identity. But the status of this identity is "ISSUED". While the status of admin identity is "ACTIVATED". Is this an issue?

Or am I missing out on any of the important step here?

Comment: I'm guessing you're using a persistent REST Server - if so, see the Google OAUTH2 tutorial https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/google_oauth2_rest that describes what to do so the REST server admin id's connection profile can resolve fabric containers by name rather than localhost (eg ca.example.com etc). Then you would need to delete and re-import the card in your REST wallet, before /system/ping

Comment: @PaulO'Mahony I've updated the urls in the connection profile before starting the persistent REST Server. Basically, I've java services that are consuming the REST APIs. Using this java service I'm able to create the user, create card for him and import this card into the server as well. However, when I use "docker exec" and try to navigate into .composer directory, I'm not able see the imported cards.

Comment: Looks like you haven't mounted the volume, as shown in this tutorial (docker run sequence) -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/deploying-the-rest-server  - then the business cards would be available to the REST server - the  local business network card store is mounted into the REST server Docker container by specifying -v ~/.composer:/home/composer/.composer. This permits the REST server to access and use the local business network card store - you may already be doing this. Its all captured in that tutorial. Good luck!

Comment: Hi @PaulO'Mahony, I pruned the network and updated the base connection profile file and the script that generates the cards. I changed the URLs over there instead of modifying the cards after creating them. This has solved the issue as now the cards are generated with proper container URLs rather than localhost. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @MrudavShukla, i send you an email, you can help me with this??
Thank you!! 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57187913/hyperledger-composer-ping-on-rest-multi-user-mode-econnrefused-for-issued-ident