# Hyperledger Composer ping on REST multi-user mode: ECONNREFUSED for issued identities from single user REST

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Following: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/tutorials/google_oauth2_rest

I have the same problem of:

[Hyperledger Composer multi-user mode: ECONNREFUSED for issued identities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52422806/hyperledger-composer-multi-user-mode-econnrefused-for-issued-identities)

Basically, i have two rest server and when i issue a id from port 3001 (admin card single user) then import and try to ping on port 3000 (multi-user), the same error appears. Seems like the card are being imported with the wrong hostname.

But i can't do the same that the user says:
" I changed the URLs over there instead of modifying the cards after creating them. This has solved the issue as now the cards are generated with proper container URLs rather than localhost. "

When i do

```
composer identity issue -c admin@amachains -f restadmin.card -u restadmin -a "resource:org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin#restadmin"

composer card import -f restadmin.card

composer network ping -c restadmin@amachains

cd ..

sed -e 's/localhost:7051/peer0.org1.example.com:7051/' -e 's/localhost:7053/peer0.org1.example.com:7053/' -e 's/localhost:7054/ca.org1.example.com:7054/'  -e 's/localhost:7050/orderer.example.com:7050/'  < $HOME/.composer/cards/restadmin@amachains/connection.json  > /tmp/connection.json && cp -p /tmp/connection.json $HOME/.composer/cards/restadmin@amachains/
```

and then export this and import in 3000 rest server, the ping works.

That is my script for start my whole project:

```
# !/bin/bash
sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:3000)

sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:3001)

sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:4200)

# Stop Fabric & Teardown Fabric
~/fabric-dev-servers/stopFabric.sh && ~/fabric-dev-servers/teardownFabric.sh

# Clean Composer
rm -rf ~/.composer

# Clean Docker containers
docker kill $(docker ps -q)

docker rm $(docker ps -aq)

# Clean Docker images
docker rmi $(docker images dev-* -q)

# Clean Docker images
docker rmi $(docker images amachains/* -q)

# Start Fabric & Create Peer Admin Card
~/fabric-dev-servers/startFabric.sh && ~/fabric-dev-servers/createPeerAdminCard.sh

docker run -d --name mongo --network composer_default -p 27017:27017 mongo

cd dockertmp

docker build -t amachains/amachains-rest-server .

cd ..

# Install BNA on Hyperledger Faric with Hyperledger Composer
cd ./amachains-bna

composer archive create -t dir -n .

composer network install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --archiveFile amachains@0.0.1.bna

composer network start --networkName amachains --networkVersion 0.0.1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --file networkadmin.card

composer card import --file networkadmin.card

composer network ping -c admin@amachains

composer participant add -c admin@amachains -d '{"$class":"org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin", "participantId":"restadmin"}'

composer identity issue -c admin@amachains -f restadmin.card -u restadmin -a "resource:org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin#restadmin"

composer card import -f restadmin.card

composer network ping -c restadmin@amachains

cd ..

sed -e 's/localhost:7051/peer0.org1.example.com:7051/' -e 's/localhost:7053/peer0.org1.example.com:7053/' -e 's/localhost:7054/ca.org1.example.com:7054/'  -e 's/localhost:7050/orderer.example.com:7050/'  < $HOME/.composer/cards/restadmin@amachains/connection.json  > /tmp/connection.json && cp -p /tmp/connection.json $HOME/.composer/cards/restadmin@amachains/ 

source envvars.txt

docker run \
-d \
-e COMPOSER_CARD=${COMPOSER_CARD} \
-e COMPOSER_NAMESPACES=${COMPOSER_NAMESPACES} \
-e COMPOSER_AUTHENTICATION=${COMPOSER_AUTHENTICATION} \
-e COMPOSER_MULTIUSER=${COMPOSER_MULTIUSER} \
-e COMPOSER_PROVIDERS="${COMPOSER_PROVIDERS}" \
-e COMPOSER_DATASOURCES="${COMPOSER_DATASOURCES}" \
-v ~/.composer:/home/composer/.composer \
--name rest \
--network composer_default \
-p 3000:3000 \
amachains/amachains-rest-server

# docker ps |grep rest

# docker logs -f rest

cd amachains-client/

composer-rest-server -c admin@amachains -p 3001 & npm start
```

system/ping on rest server port 3000 should be ok status but i get:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): HttpErrorResponse: {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null},"status":500,"statusText":"Internal Server Error","url":"http://localhost:3000/api/system/ping","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/api/system/ping: 500 Internal Server Error","error":{"error":{"statusCode":500,"name":"Error","message":"Error trying login and get user Context. Error: Error trying to enroll user. Error: Calling enrollment endpoint failed with error [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:7054]","stack":"Error: Error trying login and get user Context. Error: Error trying to enroll user. Error: Calling enrollment endpoint failed with error [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:7054]\n    at HLFConnection.login (/home/composer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:477:30)\n    at <anonymous>\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)"}}}
```

Comment: Have you tried updating the connection profile associated with the identity before pushing your card to the docker container?

Comment: Yes, im doing this: 

sed -e 's/localhost:7051/peer0.org1.example.com:7051/' -e 's/localhost:7053/peer0.org1.example.com:7053/' -e 's/localhost:7054/ca.org1.example.com:7054/'  -e 's/localhost:7050/orderer.example.com:7050/'  < $HOME/.composer/cards/restadmin@amachains/connection.json  > /tmp/connection.json && cp -p /tmp/connection.json $HOME/.composer/cards/restadmin@amachains/

Comment: But i dont know how to update the connection profile of one card generated from multi-user rest server client...